# Subclassed node, but want to detect touch in the scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a subclassed node called LocationNode, where touch is enabled. It looks like this.

```
class LocationNode: SKSpriteNode, CustomNodeEvents {
func didMoveToScene() {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
}
```

I haven't overriden touchesBegan in this subclass file, because I want to control all touch events like this in the actual scene file:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)

    //if touchedNode.name != nil {
        print("touched")
    //}
}
```

When I try do this, however, it doesn't work. How can I control touch events for a subclassed node in the scene file?

EDIT:

Here's what my override function looks like in the scene.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)
    print("TOUCHED")
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this: "I haven't overriden touchesBegan in this scene, because I want to control all touch events like this in the actual scene file:"

Comment: Sorry, I've edited this now.

Comment: You should disable user interaction on subclassed node

Comment: @Whirlwind Thank you -- that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this code below in your custom class, in this case `LocationNode`, to have a "return of touches" to the parent class, then you can handle the touches in both places (also to the main scene) :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            print("touched!")
        }
        guard let parent = self.parent else { return }
        parent.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the guard is supposed to return the touches to the parent class (in this case, SKSpriteNode, and the scene), but it doesn't seem to be working. The second part of it works, though (meaning that it still handles its own touch events within the subclass).

Comment: The guard part is to be sure your class have a parent, if the second part works means also you have a parent

Comment: OK, thanks, makes sense now. I've added what the override function looks like in the scene. When a locationNode is touched, it should fire "TOUCHED!" from the parent function but it doesn't.

Comment: Take a look at this improvement, the touches always happen inside the class and if you have a parent happen also to the main scene.The only thing you can verify now, is what is the parent? because you have posted too few code in your question so I cannot say more about it..

Comment: When I disabled user interaction in the subclassed node, this approach worked. Thank you.